# X509 Name Constraints in a 3-tier PKI - setting at the intermediate CA?

Tags: certificates, pki

I have been playing around with implementing a three-tier PKI recently. My PKI structure is as follows:

- Root CA

  - Intermediate CA 1 (Name constraint: DNS .example.com, Email: .example.com, pathlen 1)
  - Intermediate CA 2 (Name constraint: DNS: .example.org, Email: .example.org, pathlen 1)

    - VPN Application CA (EKU Constraint, e.g. for IPSec/IKEv2, pathlen 0)

I've set up all my AIAs, CRL distribution points, and everything works fine. However, I issued a VPN client certificate for "user@vpn.example.org" (since .example.org doesn't apply to the top-level domain); however, when I go to use the certificate in StrongSwan, I get the following error:

```
using trusted intermediate ca certificate "(VPN Application CA)"
using trusted intermediate ca certificate "(Intermediate CA 2)"
intermediate CA "(VPN Application CA)" does not inherit permitted name constraint ".example.org"
```

And it fails to authenticate the user. Disabling the "constraints" plugin in StrongSwan permits the authentication request to succeed.

Verifying the end-entity certificate with certutil on Windows goes fine - it says the name constraints are valid and everything. `openssl verify` also validates the certificate without issue.

I was under the impression that a name constraint anywhere in the certificate chain would propagate downwards, but that it wasn't required on subordinate CAs if set on a parent. Is that not the case?